# How to store dropdown menu to localstorage

Tags: javascript, html, css, local-storage

I have a problem with a dropdown menu. When I refresh the page, I want it to show the previous selection. Probably my knowledge is very poor in this area and a detailed explanation would be appreciated. I can see that the data is stored, but for some reason is not loaded.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Countries</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="loader"></div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <header class="header-section">
            <div class="where-to-go-container">
                <h1>Where in the world?</h1>
                <input type="search" name="" id="searchCountry" placeholder="Search for a country..">
            </div>
            <div class="functional-dark-dropdown">
                <input type="checkbox" id="darkmode-toggle">
                <label for="darkmode-toggle"></label>
                <select name="" id="dropdown-region">
                    <option value="Asia">Asia</option>
                    <option value="Europe">Europe</option>
                    <option value="Americas">America</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </header>
        <section class="all-countries" id="countries">
            
        </section>
    </div>
    <script src="restapi.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Instrument+Sans&display=swap');
.wrapper {
    margin: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    font-family: 'Instrument Sans', sans-serif;
    display: none;
}
.loader {
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
    background: #040000;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top:50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    animation: animloader 1s ease-in infinite;
  }
  
  @keyframes animloader {
    0% {
      transform: scale(0);
      opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
      transform: scale(1);
      opacity: 0;
    }
  }  
.dark-mode{
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
.header-section {
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    z-index: 1;
    position: fixed;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: end;
    top:0;
    
}
label {
    width: 50px;
    height: 20px;
    position: relative;
    top:-25px;
    left: 25px;
    display: block;
    background-color: #ebebeb;
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: inset 0.5px 1.5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), inset 0px -0.5px 1.5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
}
label::after {
    content: "";
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1px;
    left: 1px;
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, #ffcc89, #d8860b);
    border-radius: 18px;
    box-shadow: 0;
    transition: 0.3s;
}
#darkmode-toggle {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}
#darkmode-toggle:checked + label {
    background: #242424;
}
#darkmode-toggle:checked + label::after{
    left:49px;
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    background: linear-gradient(180deg,#777,#3a3a3a);
}
label:active:after{
    width: 26px;
}
#searchCountry{
    border: none;
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: inset 0.5px 1.5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), inset 0px -0.5px 1.5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
    padding: 5px;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: #ebebeb;
}
#dropdown-region{
    border: none;
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: inset 0.5px 1.5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), inset 0px -0.5px 1.5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #ebebeb;
}
.functional-dark-dropdown{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.all-countries{
    margin-top: 150px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
.country-card{
    width: 200px;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16) 0px 1px 4px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 75%;
    background: #ebebeb;
    color: black !important;
}
.country-card:hover{
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35) 0px 5px 15px;
}
.card-darkmode{
    box-shadow: rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.16) 0px 1px 4px;
}
.country-card img{
    width: 160px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
@media (max-width:720px) {
    .header-section{
        width: 90%;
    }
    .header-section h1{
        font-size: 22px;
    }
    #searchCountry{
        width:200px;
    }
    .all-countries{
        margin-top: 100px;
    }
}
```

**src="restapi.js"**

```
const apiUrl = 'https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all';

async function getCountries() {
    try {
        const response = await fetch(apiUrl);
        const data = await response.json();
        return data;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching countries:', error);
        return [];
    }
}
```

**src="script.js"**

```
const darkModeToggle = document.getElementById("darkmode-toggle");
function toggleDarkMode() {
    const elementBody = document.body;
    elementBody.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
}
darkModeToggle.addEventListener("click", toggleDarkMode);

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', async function () {
    const countriesContainer = document.getElementById('countries');
    const searchInput = document.getElementById('searchCountry');
    const regionDropdown = document.getElementById('dropdown-region');

    const countriesData = await getCountries();

    function renderCountries(countries) {
        countriesContainer.innerHTML = '';

        countries.forEach(country => {
            const countryCard = document.createElement('div');
            countryCard.classList.add('country-card');

            const heading = document.createElement('h2');
            heading.textContent = country.name.common;

            const regionParagraph = document.createElement('p');
            regionParagraph.textContent = `Region: ${country.region}`;

            const capitalParagraph = document.createElement('p');
            capitalParagraph.textContent = `Capital: ${country.capital}`;

            const flagImage = document.createElement('img');
            flagImage.src = country.flags.png;
            flagImage.alt = `${country.name.common} flag`;

            countryCard.appendChild(heading);
            countryCard.appendChild(regionParagraph);
            countryCard.appendChild(capitalParagraph);
            countryCard.appendChild(flagImage);

            countriesContainer.appendChild(countryCard);
        });
    }
    renderCountries(countriesData);

    function debounce(func, delay = 300) {
        let timerId;
        return (...args) => {
            clearTimeout(timerId);
            timerId = setTimeout(() => {
                func.apply(this, args);
            }, delay);
        };
    }
    function searchFunc() {
        const searchTerm = searchInput.value.toLowerCase();
        const filteredCountries = countriesData.filter(country =>
            country.name.common.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm)
        );
        renderCountries(filteredCountries);
    }
    const debouncedSearchFunc = debounce(searchFunc);
    searchInput.addEventListener('input', debouncedSearchFunc);

    function saveSelectedRegion(selectedRegion) {
        localStorage.setItem("lastSelectedRegion", selectedRegion);
    }
    function getLastSelectedRegion() {
        return localStorage.getItem("lastSelectedRegion");
    }
    function loadLastSelectedRegion() {
        const lastSelectedRegion = getLastSelectedRegion();
        regionDropdown.value = lastSelectedRegion;
        const filteredCountries = countriesData.filter(country =>
            country.region.toLowerCase() === lastSelectedRegion.toLowerCase()
        );
        renderCountries(filteredCountries);
    }
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        loadLastSelectedRegion();
    });

    regionDropdown.addEventListener('change', function () {
        const selectedRegion = regionDropdown.value;
        const filteredCountries = countriesData.filter(country =>
            country.region.toLowerCase() === selectedRegion.toLowerCase()
        );
        renderCountries(filteredCountries);
        saveSelectedRegion(selectedRegion);
    });
});

let loadingTimer;
function loadingPage() {
    loadingTimer = setTimeout(showPage, 2000);
}
function showPage() {
    clearTimeout(loadingTimer);
    document.querySelector(".loader").style.display = "none";
    document.querySelector(".wrapper").style.display = "flex";
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", loadingPage);
```

Comment: @Yogi I thought so, didnt know ho to google the solution.

Comment: @Yogi thank you so much. I spent 2 days checking everything but this